# Can you find the datasheet for this IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, configuration

Can someone help me to identify this VISHAY IC? Tips on how to do this are also welcome :). I could not find anything by searching with the numbers on top of the IC. The IC is used in a MKS 649B Pressure Controller.

[image: unkown VISHAY IC]

Comment: You need to consider it in context.  What sort of connections does it have?  What do you observe on it in operation.  And why do you care?

Answer (score 5):

Been searching the internet top to toe for an answer too, I think the best I could come up with alongside the H bridge was this [Vishay resistor network ic.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/60003/vtsrvssr.pdf) The naming on the datasheet doesn’t line up at all so not convinced I’m correct, but just thought I’d share.

Comment: The PCB layout for the MKS649B is shown on page 39 of the manual: https://www.idealvac.com/files/manuals/MKS-649B-MAN.pdf  This denotes the 24 pin IC as 'RN1' - so I suspect you are correct, it is a resistor network IC. Maybe something made as a 'special' with non-standard value resistors - hence no standard part number on the device

Answer (score 4):

I cant comment as I don't have enough points, so I will submit this as an answer: [closest I could find](https://www.tme.eu/Document/fd52795cf1b934d590942b4f36db0513/SI9978DW-E3.pdf). It is an IC made by Vishay with the correct package (SOIC-24(W)) as far as I can guess. And I only found it by using different search terms with some terms between hyphens.

I guess this could be the correct IC, as the one I found is an H-bridge driver, so this one could be used to power the pump of the pressurizer.

Comment: Good shout, but not a SOIC24 package. SOIC packages are 1.27mm pitch - pin pitch on the IC shown is far too small.